# SecContentInjection is not yet supported

Tags: nginx, mod-security, mod-security2, nginx-config

I am getting below error when using ContentInjection rule

> vi /etc/nginx/nginx.conf nginx -s reload 10:26:25 [notice] 118#118:
>   ModSecurity-nginx v1.0.0 10:26:25 [emerg] 118#118: "modsecurity_rules"
>   directive Rules error. File: <>.
>   Line: 1. Column: 16. SecContentInjection is not yet supported.  in
>   /etc/nginx/nginx
>
> rg] "modsecurity_rules" directive Rules error. File: <>. Line: 1. Column: 16. SecContentInjection is
>   not yet supported.  in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:66

Answer (score 0):

It's not supported in libModSecurity 3.0. And I am not sure, it is impossible to bring this feature to nginx the way it used to work on Apache.